# problem with currency masking with v-mask

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

buddy,

I use v-mask and text-mask-addons plugins. When I make currency settings, the input deletes the value after 6 digits. But when I add a prefix, there is no such problem. an infinite number of values can be entered. my request is to be able to enter an infinite number of values without a prefix.

```
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';
const currencyMask = createNumberMask({
    prefix: ' ',
    allowDecimal: true,
    includeThousandsSeparator: true,
    allowNegative: false,
    thousandsSeparatorSymbol: '.',
    decimalSymbol: ',',
});

export default {
    data(){
        return {
            currencyMask: currencyMask
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `decimalLimit : 6` option?

Comment: Yep, I tried. @Raeisi